# How to split and format 2 messages to avoid a loop in NODE-RED?

Tags: node-red

I need help to do the right split & format with 2 different messages, **as the second msg is also including the first**.

The issue : the second msg is always doing a loop wen including the first. Can't find anything to stop the split in the right way, as **I can't base my split on counting => number of strings can be variable, so length also**...

**1st msg :** IWAP02,zh_cn,0,**7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7**#

Actually this right split & format result when executed alone is :

460,0,9520,3671
460,0,9520'3672
460,0,9520,3673
460,0,9520,3674
460,0,9520,3675
460,0,9520,3676
460,0,9520,3677

2nd msg :
IWAP02,zh_cn,1,**7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7**,4,1|D8-24-BD-79-FA-1F|59&2|3C-46-D8-6D-CE-01|81&3|0C-4C-39-1A-7C-65|69&4|70-A8-E3-5D-D7-C0|65#

Actually this wrong split & format result when executed including the first msg is doing :

460,0,9520,3671
460,0,9520,3672
460,0,9520,3673
460,0,9520,3674
460,0,9520,3675
460,0,9520,3676
460,0,9520,3677
460,0,4 <= here starts the loop... and I have 9 objects as I should have only 7 
460,0,1 <= (but I can't limit as it could come more).

**Below are the NODE-RED nodes to consider the whole problem:**

```
[{"id":"a44aa7ab.117b58","type":"tab","label":"Test Split","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"8f59e0b6.23c3d","type":"inject","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"LBS","topic":"","payload":"IWAP02,zh_cn,0,7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7#","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":85,"y":54,"wires":[["e93212c2.9da56"]]},{"id":"728ddf4.709982","type":"inject","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"LBS+WIFI","topic":"","payload":"IWAP02,zh_cn,1,7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7,4,1|D8-24-BD-79-FA-1F|59&2|3C-46-D8-6D-CE-01|81&3|0C-4C-39-1A-7C-65|69&4|70-A8-E3-5D-D7-C0|65#","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":93,"y":120.20001411437988,"wires":[["e93212c2.9da56"]]},{"id":"e93212c2.9da56","type":"function","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"Get flag and other parts","func":"// flag = 0 \n// IWAP02,zh_cn,0,7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7#\n\n// flag = 1\n// IWAP02,zh_cn,1,7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7,4,1|D8-24-BD-79-FA-1F|59&2|3C-46-D8-6D-CE-01|81&3|0C-4C-39-1A-7C-65|69&4|70-A8-E3-5D-D7-C0|65#\n\nmsg.elements = msg.payload.replace('#','').split(\",\"); // this gives an array containing the bits\n\n// Get flag\nmsg.flag = msg.elements[2] // 0\n\n// Get baseCountgsmTower\nmsg.baseCountgsmTower = Number(msg.elements[3]) // 7\nmsg.mmc = msg.elements[4] // 226\nmsg.mnc = msg.elements[5] // 10\n\n// Get baseCountwifiAccessPoints\nmsg.baseCountwifiAccessPoints = Number(msg.elements[13]) // 4\n\nreturn msg","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":333.00000762939453,"y":80.20001220703125,"wires":[["58eaf0fd.8870b","c1a2eeff.031dd"]]},{"id":"59f87170.6b9a6","type":"function","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"Prepare msg type 0","func":"//Prepare JS object and fill out fields before conversion to XML\n\nvar LocationRQ = {\"$\":{\"xmlns\":\"http://skyhookwireless.com/wps/2005\",\"version\":\"2.26\",\"street-address-lookup\":\"full\"},\"authentication\":[{\"$\":{\"version\":\"2.2\"},\"key\":[{\"$\":{\"key\":\"XYXYXXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXXYXYXYXYYXYXYXXY\",\"username\":\"ABABABABABABABABAAB\"}}]}],\"gsm-tower\":[]}\n\n// flag = 0 \n// IWAP02,zh_cn,0,7,226,10,1440|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7#\n\nlet elements = msg.elements; \nLocationRQ.flag = msg.flag; // true or false - A or V\nLocationRQ.gsmTowerStrings = msg.gsmTowerStrings\n\n// Get LBS datas\nlet i;\nlet gsmTowerStrings = LocationRQ.gsmTowerStrings;\nlet j;\nlet gsmTower = [];\nfor (j = 6; j < msg.elements.length; j++) {\n let spl = msg.elements[j].split(\"|\")\n gsmTower.push({ mcc: msg.mmc, mnc: msg.mnc, lac: spl[0], ci: spl[1] }) // 460,0,9520|3671|\n}\n// adjust baseCountgsmTower just in case the number actually there didn't match that expexted\nLocationRQ.baseCountgsmTower = gsmTower.length\nLocationRQ[\"gsm-tower\"] = gsmTower;\n\nmsg.payload = {LocationRQ: LocationRQ};\nreturn msg\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":558,"y":177.20001316070557,"wires":[["904565e.bfb9798","e738a0af.fdfe4"]]},{"id":"e738a0af.fdfe4","type":"function","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"Format msg 0","func":"delete msg.flag;\ndelete msg.elements;\ndelete msg.baseCountgsmTower;\ndelete msg.mmc;\ndelete msg.mnc;\ndelete msg.baseCountwifiAccessPoints;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.flag;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.gsmTowerStrings;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.baseCountgsmTower;\n\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":546,"y":209.20001411437988,"wires":[["67257b91.944644"]]},{"id":"c1a2eeff.031dd","type":"switch","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"Route 0/1","property":"flag","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"eq","v":"0","vt":"str"},{"t":"eq","v":"1","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":true,"outputs":2,"x":230,"y":237.20001602172852,"wires":[["59f87170.6b9a6"],["13a76d16.cad7d3"]]},{"id":"58eaf0fd.8870b","type":"debug","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":271.00001525878906,"y":112.20001411437988,"wires":[]},{"id":"13a76d16.cad7d3","type":"function","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"Prepare msg type 1","func":"//Prepare JS object and fill out fields before conversion to XML\n\nvar LocationRQ = {\"$\":{\"xmlns\":\"http://skyhookwireless.com/wps/2005\",\"version\":\"2.26\",\"street-address-lookup\":\"full\"},\"authentication\":[{\"$\":{\"version\":\"2.2\"},\"key\":[{\"$\":{\"key\":\"XYXYXXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXXYXYXYXYYXYXYXXY\",\"username\":\"ABABABABABABABABAAB\"}}]}],\"access-point\":[],\"gsm-tower\":[]}\n\n\n// flag = 1\n// IWAP02,zh_cn,1,7,460,0,9520|3671|13,9520|3672|12,9520|3673|11,9520|3674|10,9520|3675|9,9520|3676|8,9520|3677|7,    4,1|D8-24-BD-79-FA-1F|59&2|3C-46-D8-6D-CE-01|81&3|0C-4C-39-1A-7C-65|69&4|70-A8-E3-5D-D7-C0|65#\n\nlet elements = msg.elements; \nLocationRQ.flag = msg.flag; // 0 or 1\nLocationRQ.gsmTowerStrings = msg.gsmTowerStrings\n\n// Get LBS datas\nlet i;\nlet gsmTowerStrings = LocationRQ.gsmTowerStrings;\nlet j;\nlet gsmTower = [];\nfor (j = 6; j < msg.elements.length; j++) {\n let spl = msg.elements[j].split(\"|\")\n gsmTower.push({ mcc: msg.mmc, mnc: msg.mnc, lac: spl[0], ci: spl[1] }) // 460,0,9520|3671|\n}\n// adjust baseCountgsmTower just in case the number actually there didn't match that expexted\nLocationRQ.baseCountgsmTower = gsmTower.length\nLocationRQ[\"gsm-tower\"] = gsmTower;\n\n// Get WIFI datas \nlet k;\nlet wifiAccessPointsStrings = elements[14].split(\"&\");\nlet l;\nlet ap = [];\nfor (l = 0; l < wifiAccessPointsStrings.length; l++) {\n let baseElements = wifiAccessPointsStrings[l].split(\"|\")\n ap.push({ mac: baseElements[1].replace(/:/g,\"\"), ssid: baseElements[0], [\"signal-strength\"]: baseElements[2] }) \n}\n// adjust baseCountwifiAccessPoints just in case the number actually there didn't match that expexted\nLocationRQ.baseCountwifiAccessPoints = ap.length\nLocationRQ[\"access-point\"] = ap;\n\n\nmsg.payload = {LocationRQ: LocationRQ};\nreturn msg\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":556,"y":285.2000141143799,"wires":[["81bcd4ed.43f208","e479155e.84e108"]]},{"id":"e479155e.84e108","type":"function","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"Format msg 1","func":"\ndelete msg.flag;\ndelete msg.elements;\ndelete msg.baseCountgsmTower;\ndelete msg.mmc;\ndelete msg.mnc;\ndelete msg.baseCountwifiAccessPoints;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.flag;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.gsmTowerStrings;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.baseCountgsmTower;\ndelete msg.payload.LocationRQ.baseCountwifiAccessPoints;\nvar msg1={};\n\nmsg1.payload=msg.payload;\nreturn msg1;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":545,"y":317.2000102996826,"wires":[["a65ccf87.8c1d1"]]},{"id":"81bcd4ed.43f208","type":"debug","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":788.0000114440918,"y":315.20001316070557,"wires":[]},{"id":"a65ccf87.8c1d1","type":"debug","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":788.0000114440918,"y":355.2000141143799,"wires":[]},{"id":"904565e.bfb9798","type":"debug","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":794.0000114440918,"y":155.20001316070557,"wires":[]},{"id":"67257b91.944644","type":"debug","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":795.0000114440918,"y":196.20001316070557,"wires":[]},{"id":"e27fa2d2.cb2a1","type":"comment","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"SPLIT AND FORMAT OK","info":"","x":572.2999877929688,"y":144.8000030517578,"wires":[]},{"id":"1cc4508d.135d9f","type":"comment","z":"a44aa7ab.117b58","name":"LOOP SPLIT AND FORMAT ISSUE","info":"","x":601.0000076293945,"y":251.00000190734863,"wires":[]}]
```

[image: Schema NODE-RED]

Comment: I think you have a scope problem where the field that is holding the splits is not being reset.

Comment: Solved... by myself!!! Thanks anyway...

Comment: @jenrisdeveau then please provide the answer.